# javascript global variables visibility

Tags: javascript

I'm using a global variable in javascript, declared in a script tag outside any function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var prov_status_dict={};
        ....
</script>
```

Later on in a javascript method I'm using the variable normally.

```
temp=prov_status_dict[current_as_id];
```

I'm having issues with it on opera and ie, while on firefox it works. This is what opera's error console reports:

```
JavaScript - http://localhost:8000/input/
Event thread: click
Error:
name: ReferenceError
message: Statement on line 62: Undefined variable: prov_status_dict
stacktrace: n/a; see  opera:config#UserPrefs|Exceptions Have Stacktrace
```

I've noticed that the problem is with global variables in general. I tryed moving some into hidden fields, but the same error pops up on the next use of a global var.

Help?

Comment: The code as you describe it should work, and indeed does work on Opera when I run a simple test using the same variable name and splitting the declaration and use across two different script blocks, so there must be something more to it than you are showing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually access my globals through the window object so that I always have a point of reference

```
window.MyVariables = {};
window.MyVariables.prov_status_dict = {};
```

Give this a try, it might resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using global variables, see `http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination`